# GWT tokenizer: How to change URL

Tags: gwt, gwt-activities, gwt-places

I am using Activities and Places.

I have a LoginPlace.

The url displayed when I navigate to that place has this at the end:

```
#LoginPlace:login
```

How can I change this to just #login or something else?

My tokenizer looks like this:

```
public class LoginTokenizer implements PlaceTokenizer<LoginPlace> {

    private LoginPlace loginPlace;

    public LoginTokenizer() {
    }

    @Override
    public LoginPlace getPlace(String token) {
        return new LoginPlace(token);
    }

    @Override
    public String getToken(LoginPlace place) {
        loginPlace = place;
        return loginPlace.getLoginToken();
    }
}
```

And navigation to the LoginPlace is done through the PlaceController:

```
clientFactory.getPlaceController().goTo(new LoginPlace("login"));
```

Where can I manipulate the format of the URL?

Answer (score 1):

The mapping is done by the `PlaceHistoryMapper`.

You can have an implementation generated by GWT based in `PlaceTokenizer`s, but then it's based on a prefix/suffix. The `@Prefix` allows you configure the prefix (which otherwise defaults to the place class' name).

Or you can implement the interface yourself and have complete control over the process.

Answer (score 0):

1. Rename the Place class from `LoginPlace` to `Login`.
2. Pass an empty token:

   ```
   new LoginPlace("")
   ```

Comment: Hey! It's weird that I would have to change the name of my class. Are you sure this is the only way?

Comment: As Thomas noted you can use a @Prefix annotation, but changing the class name is the simplest way to do it. I prefer this option because it is easier to maintain and understand, especially in large apps with many different places.